How to leverage previous value in dax without yielding a circular dependency?

Hi there,
I'm trying to calculate the ideal rate based upon the SUM of the previous ideal rates.

The first row will always just be the [New Orders] / [Hours Remaining]. So, in this example, 1,322/8 = 165.25.
However, from row 2:n, I want the ideal rate to be the (Cumulative SUM of [New Orders] - Cumulative SUM of the prior [Ideal Rates]) / [Hours Remaining]. So to use three examples:

Row 2: ((1,322 + 0) - 165.25) / 7 = 165.25
Row 3: ((1,322 + 0 + 38) - (165.25 + 165.25)) / 6
Row 4: ((1,322 + 0 + 38 + 5) - (165.25 + 165.25 + 171.58)) / 5



I'm struggling to figure out out to reference the prior row rates to adjust the cumulative orders.
New Orders = DistinctCount(Orders[Order_Number])
Hours Remaining = DATEDIFF(MAX('Time'[Time]),CALCULATE(MAX('Time'[Time]),REMOVEFILTERS('Time'[Time])),HOUR)
Ideal Rate = 

VAR Time = CALCULATE(MIN('Time'[Time]),ALLSELECTED('Time'))
VAR CurrentRowRate = DIVIDE([New Orders],[Hours Remaining],0)
VAR CumOrders = 
    CALCULATE(
        [New Orders],
        WINDOW(0,ABS,0,REL,ALLSELECTED('Time'[Time]))
    )
VAR CumPriorRowRates = 
    CALCULATE(
        CumOrders - CurrentRowRate,
        WINDOW(0,ABS,-1,REL,ALLSELECTED('Time'[Time]))
    )
VAR AdjustedCurrentRowRate = 
    CumPriorRowRates  / [Hours Remaining]
RETURN

IF(MAX('Time'[Time]) = Time,
   CurrentRowRate,
   AdjustedCurrentRowRate)

I've been able to implement this in an R Visual by iteratively referencing the prior cumulative sum. However, ideally,  I wanted to do this in DAX.
for (i in 1:nrow(Orders_By_Hour)) {
  
  Orders_By_Hour$Ideal_Rate[i] <- ifelse(Orders_By_Hour$Time[i] == min(Orders_By_Hour$Time),
      Orders_By_Hour$Cum_Orders[i]/Orders_By_Hour$Hours_Remaining[i],
      (Orders_By_Hour$ending_sum[i-1]+Orders_By_Hour$New_Orders[i])/Orders_By_Hour$Hours_Remaining[i])
  
  Orders_By_Hour$ending_sum[i] <- ifelse(Orders_By_Hour$Time[i] == min(Orders_By_Hour$Time),
                              Orders_By_Hour$Cum_Orders[i] - Orders_By_Hour$Ideal_Rate[i],
                              Orders_By_Hour$ending_sum[i-1]+Orders_By_Hour$New_Orders[i] - Orders_By_Hour$Ideal_Rate[i])
  
}

Stack Overflow Articles Referenced:

Bring previous day value as starting point for next day in a measure within Power BI
Self-reference a column in DAX or Power Query

Youtube Videos Referenced:

SOLVE Circular Dependency issues in Recursive Inventory problems | MAGIC of WINDOW() + OFFSET()
Microsoft Hates Greg - Previous Value ("Recursion") in DAX


I don't think this is possible for your given scenario. Are you able to replicate what you need in Excel with a consistent column formula?

With exception to the first row, I could do (SUM(New Orders[Starting Row:Current Row])-SUM(Ideal Rate[Starting Row:Current Row - 1))/Hours Remaining[Current Row]

We can simplify your formula to simply:
for this row and all previous rows, sum (orders divided by hours, for each row)

Then you can use this measure:
Ideal Rate = 
  SUMX(
    WINDOW(0,ABS,0,REL,ALLSELECTED('Time'[Time])),
    DIVIDE([New Orders], [Hours Remaining])
  )



This is amazing. Would you mind taking me back to math 101 and explain to me how the row by row calculation is equal to the cumulative minus the aggregate previous rates?

I'm not a math wiz, I will try though. Focusing on 2nd row, it can be rewritten as 0/7 +(1,322 - 165.25) / 7, and if we focus on the second part... https://www.symbolab.com/solver/pre-algebra-calculator/%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(x-%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7By%7D%5Cright)%7D%7By-1%7D?or=input which simplifies to previous row orders / previous Hrs remaining, so we cumulative sum that calculation for each row.
